# Installing PostgreSQL on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, postgresql

I am starting to use PostgreSQL on my Mac but I am stumped as to how I should go about it

I tried out instructions given in the below sites :

http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/21/install-postgresql-on-mac-os-x-via-brew/
https://www.codementor.io/devops/tutorial/getting-started-postgresql-server-mac-osx
https://gist.github.com/sgnl/609557ebacd3378f3b72

but to little avail.

Here is my terminal log:-

```
Pavan7Vasans-MacBook-Pro:~ pavan7vasan$ brew install postgresql
Updating Homebrew...
Warning: postgresql 9.6.5 is already installed
Pavan7Vasans-MacBook-Pro:~ pavan7vasan$ postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5
Pavan7Vasans-MacBook-Pro:~ pavan7vasan$ psql postgres
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Pavan7Vasans-MacBook-Pro:~ pavan7vasan$ which postgresql
Pavan7Vasans-MacBook-Pro:~ pavan7vasan$ which postgres
/usr/local/php5/bin/postgres
Pavan7Vasans-MacBook-Pro:~ pavan7vasan$ postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
LOG:  unrecognized configuration parameter "dynamic_shared_memory_type" in file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf" line 126
FATAL:  configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf" contains errors
Pavan7Vasans-MacBook-Pro:~ pavan7vasan$ postgres -D 
/usr/local/php5/bin/postgres 
postgres cannot access the server configuration file 
"/usr/local/php5/bin/postgres/postgresql.conf": Not a directory
Pavan7Vasans-MacBook-Pro:~ pavan7vasan$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start && brew services start postgresql
server starting
LOG:  unrecognized configuration parameter "dynamic_shared_memory_type" in file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf" line 126
FATAL:  configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf" contains errors
Service `postgresql` already started, use `brew services restart 
postgresql` to restart.
Pavan7Vasans-MacBook-Pro:~ pavan7vasan$ brew services restart postgresql
Stopping `postgresql`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
Pavan7Vasans-MacBook-Pro:~ pavan7vasan$ postgres -V
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5
Pavan7Vasans-MacBook-Pro:~ pavan7vasan$
```

what has me in a fix is that despite the latest version of PostgreSQL being installed through homebrew, the current version is 9.3.5

Is this because of an older version of PostgreSQL present as shown through the `which postgres` command is conflicting?

Are all the above errors due to the older version still being the current version?

If possible, how do I change the version to the latest version?

Please do tell me what is to be done

Comment: You seem to have an old version of PG installed in a PHP directory.  Do you need that?  The obvious fix is to uninstall that PHP.

Comment: Is there a chance that I can update PG in the said directory? or in the worst case, how should I remove the PG installed in that PHP directory? I don't know which installer I used

Comment: Without knowing how it was installed, I can't guess how to upgrade it, or if it's safe to remove.